# uninstall android application from inside the application?

Tags: android, security, passwords, uninstallation

Hi friends my question is little complicated.I am currently making an password related project ie, the app only open when user enter his/her password.While developing the application i figured that my application can only open by entering the password ,but what if any stranger/friends  take my phone and uninstall my application .Then all the data that store in my app will be destroyed.so i am thinking that ask a password before uninstalling the app or  disable the uninstall button form the application uninstalling process  ie, the uninstall button should only enable when i do some thing from inside my app.now is that possible if so please replay

Comment: you could make an uninstall app...

Comment: what do u mean?can we make a uninstall application please ex-plane

Answer (score 1):

Not possible I'm afraid. Lock the phone with a password instead.

Comment: so can i ask you some thing  what is the security for any app in android,any one can uninstall our necessary application?

Answer (score 0):

There some apps, which allow starting app only after you enter password. 
They all utilize system logs, i.e. by reading that log you know when certain Activity starts.
And, you can "intercept" that. So, maybe that will help you.